# some problem during show a geoserver tiff with openlayer

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I tried to use openlayer to show geoserver tif, but it shows not correctly. Here are my steps:
1. I choose a tif from local geoserver, for example(topp:states)
2. then trying to load it with openlayer api

```
const tifMap = (target) => {

new Map({
    target,
    pixelRatio: 1,
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states',  
                'BBOX': '-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735', 
                'CRS': 'EPSG:4326', 
                'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg',
                'VERSION': '1.1.0'
            },
            serverType: 'geoserver'  
        })

      })
    ],
    view: new View({
      center: [741189, -3741196],
      zoom: 4
    })
  })
};
```

3. unfortunately, several same image show on the div, I don't know why, actually I tried to open the link **(openlayer tried to get)** via browser, it shows normal.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers automatically creates BBOX and CRS parameters based on the projection set in the source options and the tile grid for TileWMS or viewport for ImageWMS.  A maximum extent can be set either in the tilegrid (in server projection units) or on the layer (in view projection units).  Assuming the server only supported EPSG:4326 and you wished to display a tiled output as EPSG:3857  either of these would work:

```
  new TileLayer({
    source: new TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states',  
            'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg',
            'VERSION': '1.1.0'
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        projection: 'EPSG:4326' 
    }),
    extent: transformExtent([-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
  })
```

.

```
  new TileLayer({
    source: new TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states',  
            'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg',
            'VERSION': '1.1.0'
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver',  
        projection: 'EPSG:4326', 
        tilegrid: createXYZ({extent: [-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735]})
    })
  })
```